# FQL Facebook query and strange LIMIT behavior

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Well i got alot of posts in my stream but when i do:

SELECT type,source_id,actor_id,post_id,type,attachment,message,permalink,description,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = xxx ORDER BY created_time DESC limit 15

it only returns 7 rows... it shouldn't returns 15 rows?

someone could explain it for me?

thanks.

Comment: Are there 15 records to return? Is it possible only 7 match the query?

Comment: yes, i got more than 15 rows...

Comment: if i increase the limit to 80, it returns more rows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `stream` FQL queries, Facebook first finds all the posts that match your query, then filters these results for those that are publicly viewable before passing them to the API.

In your case, Facebook is finding 15 queries, but 8 of them are not viewable by your authorization token, so only 7 get returned.